# How to get text in current buffer in neovim using Python API?

Tags: python, neovim

I want to make a plugin for neovim using the Python API (pynvim). The problem is I want to get the current buffer's text, updated real time. I have searched on the web and didnt find any useful (or understandable) documentation for this.

Comment: how is it going this ? i'm trying something like that but the documentation is really horrible

Comment: @soyunewok yes i gave up. although i think you can ask in neovim gitter

Comment: i found something, at the moment detect when i typing, but i still not capture the text. do you still interest ?

Comment: @soyunewok feel free to tweak my answer as needed. It mostly gets you to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pynvim to subscribe to an event in neovim. Do keep in mind that pynvim is async, but my example is using a simple while loop do demonstrate how to monitor for realtime change in a buffer and get its content.

```py
from time import sleep
from pynvim import attach, api

nvim = attach('socket', path='/tmp/nvim')

buffer = nvim.current.buffer

event = api.nvim.Nvim.from_nvim(nvim) # use the loaded nvim session
listen = event.subscribe('TextChangedI') # refer to events https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html#events

while True:
    sleep(2)
    print(listen)
    # read and print contents of the whole buffer
    for line in range(len(buffer)):
        print(buffer[line])
```